# Añadir nuevos elementos (PHP) Object Std Class

Tags: php, json

Dado el siguiente conjunto de datos, me he bloqueado y no sé cómo agregar nuevos campos. Aquí un ejemplo de la salida JSON:

```
{
   "nombre":"nombre1",
   "tipo":"empresa",
   "contrato":"289",
   "precio":164,
   "factura":{
      "precioTotal":14.85,
      "descuento":5,
   "restoDatos":null,
   "producto":"producto1"
}
```

Todos estos valores salen de una tabla, pero ahora me gustaría agregar nuevos campos que vienen de otra:

```
$valoresTabla1 = array();
$valoresTabla1 = Helper::obtenerDatos($solicitud);
```

EDITO: He hecho un var_dump($valoresTabla1) y es un `object(stdClass)`. Esto cambia totalmente el asunto creo, disculpad mi error...

Aquí debo añadir nuevos campos al Object(stdClass) $valoresTabla1 como por ejemplo: "provincia" => $provincia ... etc

Edito:  El resultado que espero, es añadir nuevos elementos clave => valor al array que ya existe. Es decir, que el nuevo json quede así:

```
{
   "nombre":"nombre1",
   "tipo":"empresa",
   "contrato":"289",
   "precio":164,
   "factura":{
      "precioTotal":14.85,
      "descuento":5,
   "restoDatos":null,
   "producto":"producto1",
   "poblacion": "nombrepoblacion",
   "provincia": "nombreProvincia"
}
```

Comment: A tu pregunta la falta claridad... ¿quieres añadir nuevos elementos independientes al array o lo que quieres es añadir nuevos pares clave/valor a elementos ya existentes en el array? Por favor, [edita la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/163216/edit), da ejemplos claros del estado actual del array, de los nuevos valores y del resultado que esperas obtener, de lo contrario, habría que adivinar lo que quieres.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, lo he editado a ver si así se entiende mejor :)

Comment: puedes poner un var_dump($nuevos_valores) antes del array_merge? a ver que te esta devolviendo $nuevos_valores

Comment: Si precisamente iba a pedir algo parecido, incluso puedes poner el codigo en el cual obtienes el json.

Comment: Efectivamente, he editado nuevamente. Es un object std class y estaba tomándolo como array. Cómo puedo añadirle nuevos elementos?

Comment: Ya se entiende que es un objeto stdClass, pero no dices si dentro de ese objeto hay índices (o sea, si es un objeto que guarda otros objetos...). Supongamos que el objeto tiene un índice `0`, otro índice `1`, y así sucesivamente... ¿dónde tendrían que guardarse los nuevos elementos? ¿O bien es un objeto simple? Dependiendo de eso, las respuestas que te den funcionarán o no según esperas. Si hubieras puesto el `var_dump` del objeto se habría entendido mejor la situación. Y quizá hasta se podría resolver el problema a otro nivel, por ejemplo, al momento de crear el objeto en sí.

Comment: Usted tiene como opción: [array_push ()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php), [array_merge ($ actual_array, $ nuevo_array)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php), y `$ array [] = $ nuevoValor` , Buena Suerte.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prueba con

```
$valoresTabla1->miNuevoElemento = "valor";
```

Explicando, si tienes un objecto de stdClass, para agregar un elemento más solo necesitas agregarlo al objeto tal y como mencioné anteriormente

```
$objetoStdClass->nuevoElemento = "valor";
```

Comment: Hola! Gracias por tu aporte pero tu respuesta se considera de baja calidad. Considera agregar una descripción de como tu respuesta solucionaría el problema del autor. Para mas información puedes revisar [answer]

Comment: Si bien tu pregunta respuesta podría responder la cuestionante deberías colocar un explicación de lo que has hecho, :)

Comment: Hola, entiendo. Voy comenzando; la próxima respuesta trataré de explicarme mejor. Saludos :)

Answer (score 1):

Prueba en usar `array_push()`. [Documentación](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-push.php)

```
$nuevosValores = array("municipio"=>$solicitud->nombre);
$result = array_push($valoresTabla1, $nuevosValores);
```

> array_push — Inserta uno o más elementos al final de un array

Comment: De esta forma me lanza el error: "array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given", gracias por tu respuesta

Comment: Debes asegurarte que $valoresTabla1 lo has convertido a un array

Comment: lo que probablemente te suceda es que valoresTabla1 es un objeto de tipo std osea es una instancia de objeto representando un arreglo.

Comment: Disculpad mi error porque efectivamente, no es un array, hice un var_dump y es un object std class :(

Answer (score 1):

creo que esta parte no es correcta:

```
$nuevosValores = array("municipio"=>$solicitud->nombre);
$result = array_merge($valoresTabla1, $nuevosValores);
```

Si solo vas a añadir ese elemento, puedes hacer:

```
$valoresTabla1['municipio'] = $solicitud->nombre;
```

con esto te añade la clave municipio y el valor al array valoresTabla1.

Answer (score 0):

Amigo lo que debes hacer es lo siguiente

```
public function setValueResponse($tuJson,$valoresAgregar)
{
    $arrAssoc = json_decode($tuJson, true); 
    $responseWithValue = Arr::add($arrAssoc, 'user_id', $valoresAgregar);
    return json_encode($responseWithValue);
}
```

1- En la primera linea del método lo que haces es convertir tus datos en un array asociativo esto sucede cuando le pasas el valor true a la funcion Json_decode.

2- En la segunda linea con el método Arr::add (Método de Laravel) el primer parametro es tu array asociativo convertido, el segundo parametro es la clave y el tercero es el value en si

3- En la tercera linea lo vuelves otra vez a formato Json y listo puedes retornar los nuevos valores.